# How to generate a file with the names of the methods in class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this Unit Test file:

```
class WebsiteCheckPageElements < Test::Unit::TestCase

def setup
 ...
end

def test_achievements_iknow_report_page
  ...
end

def test_achievements_daily_report_page
  ...
end

def test_client_side_report_page
  ...
end
end
```

I need to write a ruby script that will write the names of the tests to .txt file. Something like

setup 
test_achievements_iknow_report_page 
test_achievements_daily_report_page 
test_client_side_report_page

Thank you in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: Why is this tagged "ruby-on-rails"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple script that uses regular expressions to print the lines that match `def`:

**`match_test_methods.rb`**

```
File.open('your_unit_test_file.rb').each_line do |line|
  match = line.match(/def (.+)/)
  puts match[1] if match
end
```

Then put the result of the script in a .txt file

```
ruby match_test_methods.rb > test_methods.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

A more robust way than the other answer:

```
File.open("test_methods.txt", "w") do |f|
  WebsiteCheckPageElements.instance_methods.each do |method|
    f << "#{method}\n"
  end
end
```

This will actually use the Ruby runtime and will not fall subject to accidentally matching `def` in places where it is not defining a method (such as inside a String), it will not match other classes in the file and it will correctly read the inheritance hierarchy.