# Pass variable in Ruby how?

Tags: ruby

Following my other question that was brilliantly solved
[How to generate a file with the names of the methods in class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910767/how-to-generate-a-file-with-the-names-of-the-methods-in-class)

Now I have another problem regarding code:

```
basedir = "."
files =  Dir.new(basedir).entries
files.each do |file|
  tests = file.match(/(.+)_tests.rb/)
  puts tests if tests
end

#here i need to use "tests" variable again .. 

tests.each do |test|
  File.open(test).each_line do |line|
    match = line.match(/def (.+)/)
    puts match[1] if match
  end
end
```

Gives me the mistake:

```
  match_test_methods.rb:10: undefined local variable or method `tests' for main:Object (NameError)
```

I guess, the problem is that "tests" variable is born and buried in the files.each do method.
How can I use it globally? Nothing worked so far...

Thanks.

Comment: Glad you solved it. You can add the solution as an answer and accept it so others know the question is answered already.

Comment: I only can do it in 8 hours because of my rating is not high enough. Just wanted to share the solution ASAP ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by fixing the code:

```
tests = []

basedir = "."
files =  Dir.new(basedir).entries

tests = files.select do |file|
   file.match(/(.+)_tests.rb/)
end

tests.each do |test|
   puts test
   File.open(test).each_line do |line|
   if match = line.match(/def (.+)/)
   puts match[1]
   end
 end
end
```

The problem was that the first method didn't return the array..

Comment: Well, that was **not the problem you asked about**. The correct answer is the one created by Mischa. A function not returning the array might be **another** problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could define it before the iteration:

```
tests = nil
basedir = "."
files =  Dir.new(basedir).entries
files.each do |file|
  tests = file.match(/(.+)_tests.rb/)
  puts tests if tests
end

# now tests will be available here
```

Answer (score 1):

You could condense this down into a single loop, to negate the need to define `tests` at a higher level.

```
basedir = "."
files =  Dir.new(basedir).entries
files.each do |file|
  tests = file.match(/(.+)_tests.rb/)
  if tests
    puts tests
    File.open(file).each_line do |line|
      match = line.match(/def (.+)/)
      puts match[1] if match
    end
  end
end
```